# How to get owners of libraries using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is it possible to get the names and owners of libraries used in a UiApp (using Google Apps Script)?

**Edit-1**
In the Script Editor you can click the `Resources` tab followed by the `Libraries...` option.
In the dialog you will see a list of libraries you're using.
I would like to obtain that list (including the versions used by the application) plus their owners by code.

Comment: "libraries used in UiApp"? I'm not sure I understand you. Can you please be more descriptive, describe your scenario, which libraries you've imported, etc. Maybe some code of what you're attempting.

Comment: I would like to make a list of resources used.  I cannot show code (yet) as I don't know where to get the info I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible. you would need the script file id from drive and use drive api to find its owner. thats not possible, you only have the script project id which is different.